# Change the order of the series items in a stacked column (Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a chart in Report Builder 3.0 that uses stacked columns to display data.  Each item in the series group has its own block on the stacked column. Because I have a large number of elements in the series group I want to change the order that these blocks display in so it's easier for users to tell which parts are more important.  Can anyone help me make a stacked column change the order in which its elements are "stacked?" Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this dynamically, or just change it at design time? As I remember the order the series are stacked is determined by the order they're added to the report, i.e. the first series in the list in the graph as specified in the designer is the first element in the stack?

Comment: Additional question that can help solving your issue - are the series fixed or dinamically changing ?

Answer (score 5):

Click on the Columns of chart. a small section will appear at right side having sections of "Values", "Category Group" and "Series Group". you can right-click on the Category Group or Series Group, go to Sorting tab, and sort the data as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a custom expression for your "Series Group"?

See [Sort Data in a Data Region (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255193.aspx).